# How can I extract the image pixels from 2D numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array

I have a matrix with a shape of (100000, 20) that consists of 20 images, each (500 *200) in size. I just need to know how can I extract those pixels so that I can have the `image shape of (500, 200)`?
I tried `matrix[:,:,19]` but it seems that I just grabbed the values of the last feature, except that this is not my goal. Also when I tried to display it with `cv2_imshow(matrix[:,:,19]`, it returns a black image.

Any help please?

Comment: Not an expert here but it’s like you flatten your image somehow. You should reshape the array to (500,200,20) ? Or am I wrong ?

Comment: Yes sure. This is what I did prior to ````matrix[:,:,19]````

Comment: Please, provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: `matrix[:,:,19]` won't work on a (1000000,20) array.  We shouldn't have to guess or deduce that you first did a reshape.  But what's this talk about 'last feature'?  Is this 20 images or 20 features?  If you don't understand what's in the array, we can't help you.

Comment: Actually, I have (500,200,20) where (500*200) are samples and 20 are features. Aren't the features supposed to represent an image ? Isnt' it the case with 20 2-dimensional image ? Please excuse my misunderstanding and I will be grateful if you will help me understand the difference between them.

Comment: @Andrea now we are curious about your input image data ? mostly about the 20 features ? fluorescent peak ? infrared values ? gamma radioation count ?  and I lost half an hour on an answer thats no good !! I wont never be able to overcome my 'no more questions allowed ban' .....

Comment: Sounds like the problem is with understanding what `matrix[:,:,i]` represents, and whether displaying it as image makes sense.  Check the `dtype`, and the range of values of `matrix`.  And then read the docs of `cv2_imshow`.  You may need to scale the matrix to get a useful display.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to reshape it:

```
import numpy as np

# after loading the images in a numpy array called imgs_array
imgs_array = imgs_array.reshape((500,200,20))
```

EDIT:
If you want to extract a single image after the reshape step, just do `single_img = imgs_array[:,:,n]` where `n` is the n-th image in the array

Comment: Thanks hrmello, do you have any idea why when I try to display it with ````cv2_imshow(imgs_array[:,:,1])````, it returns a black image ?

Comment: If imgs_array has only two dimensions, i.e. (100000,20), using imgs_array should produce an error, as you are trying to slice three dimensions. Maybe cv2_imshow is just ignoring this error and returns nothing (and then plots a black image). It should work properly, however, if imgs_array is already reshaped to (500,200,20). What is the result if you do `imgs_array[:,:,1].shape`?

By the way, don't forget to accept this or any other answer if it works for you.

Comment: @hmello but how do we know if reshape gets the right (let's call them pixel) pixels order ? we don't know how the matrix was created so reshape just gives us the right size image but maybe not the right ones ? or not ?

Comment: @pippo1980 I just assumed the images are "stacked" in order, that is, entries from 0 to 199 will become the first row, 200 to 399 the second row, and so on. If that's the case, then reshape will put it in the correct order. I've encountered such data myself a couple of times and in both of them the entries were properly ordered. E.g. create a new array `a = np.arange(125)` , check how it looks like, then use `a.reshape(5,5,5)` to visualize how reshape works.

Answer (score 0):

here my attempt at it using reshape:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Sun Jun  6 16:43:48 2021

@author: Pietro

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67859613/how-can-i-extract-the-image-pixels-from-2d-numpy-array?noredirect=1#comment119943691_67859613

"""

import numpy as np

import cv2 as cv

image_mia = np.random.choice([0,255] , (100000,20))

print(image_mia.shape) # sono le dimensioni, dimensions 

print(image_mia)

print('\n',image_mia.size)



image_mia2 = np.copy(image_mia)

print(image_mia2.shape) # sono le dimensioni, dimensions 

print(image_mia2)

print('\n',image_mia2.size)

image_mia2 = image_mia2.reshape(500,200,20)

print(image_mia2.shape) # sono le dimensioni, dimensions 

print(image_mia2)

print('\n',image_mia2.size)

img = 0

image_list = []

while img<20:
    image_list.append(image_mia2[:,:,img])
    img +=1

print(image_list)

for y,i in enumerate(image_list):
    print('\nshape : ',i.shape,'    size : ', i.size)
    
    cv.imwrite(str(y)+'.png',i.astype(np.uint8))

print('\nlenght :  ',len(image_list))
```

without code or input image I tried to guess at my best